# What does it mean when I get a server failure when connecting to a router with DNS protocol

Tags: macos, dns, superduper, wireshark

I'm currently attempting to debug a Super Duper startup problem where it takes between 10-15 seconds to start up on my machine when wireless/internet is turned on. I have communicated with Dave from Shirt Pocket who advised that Super Duper usually has a lag like this when there are network drives mounted on my machine (i.e. Super Duper would attempt to scan these resulting in the lag). When I turn wifi off, Super Duper starts up immediately.

I don't have any network drives mounted on my machine and so this has all been very mysterious.

Last night, I installed WireShark and tried to see if there's anything interesting going over the wire. I noticed that roughly around the time I start Super Duper up, I see the following in WireShark:

```
Source    | Destination | Protocol | Length | Info
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My IP     | Router IP   | DNS      | 66     | Standard query 0xd574 A System 
Router IP | My IP       | DNS      | 66     | Standard query 0xd574 Server Failure
```

The server failure is usually returns between 10-20 seconds (hence the correlation with the Super Duper start up lag). The request from my machine to the router sometimes happens repeatedly (i.e. 2 or 3 times) before the notice of failure returns from the router.

I'm not very familiar with using WireShark and reading information off packets in this way (indeed, it's very odd that this is causing any issue with Super Duper at all given that it shouldn't be going out on the network to look for stuff as I don't have any network drives setup at all on my Mac) - my question here is: does anyone know what is happening here and why do I get a server failure from my router? Internet is working with no apparent issues.

In case it becomes relevant: this is on a 2012 MacBook Air with OSX 10.9.4 plus the latest versions of Super Duper and WireShark.

Answer (score 1):

"Server failure" is, according to [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), an error that means that "The name server was unable to process this query due to a problem with the name server."  That error code doesn't provide enough information to indicate what the problem is; it could be that the router is having a problem, or it could be that the router is talking to some *other* name server and got an equally mysterious "server failure" error from *that* server.

What's the host name it's trying to look up?

Comment: No idea. According to Super Duper support it's not meant to be going out onto the network since there aren't any network drives mounted. I don't have any servers in my home network and we don't do any cross communication between different machines that connect to the wireless router.

Comment: The information you posted was from the Wireshark packet list; if you select the "Standard query 0xd574 Server Failure" packet by clicking on its line in the packet list, what does the packet detail pane show?  It should show the host name that's being queried.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear which part of the packet detail pane I get that info from. Potentially, the second section which simply lists the src as my router (D-Link...) and the dst as my mac network adapter (Apple_ee...). The last section (Domain Name system) goes into more detail with regards to the response (the flag 'Recursion desired' is set) - but nothing explicit as to what the host name is. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: Look for "Queries" in the packet detail pane, in the "Domain Name System" section, and open it up if it's not opened.

Comment: OK, here's what's in there:

System: type A, class IN
Name: System
Type: A (Host address)
Class: IN (0x0001)

Comment: OK, so *something* on your machine was looking up the host name "System".  Whether it was SuperDuper or something else is unknown.

Comment: Very strange. That's also a somewhat unfortunate name as it's next to impossible to get any useful information from Google with it. I tried adding a mapping in my hosts file to 'System' to myself (127.0.0.1) and to nothing  (0.0.0.0) - the Server Failures stopped showing up in Wireshark but the lag didn't go away. I've not noticed this DNS lookup for anything else but Super Duper (obviously can't be 100% sure) - however could this server failure be a red herring?